# how to make function in php with mysql result?

Tags: php, function

I am using same query again and again on different pages in between to fetch result. I want to make a function for this query.

```
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT name FROM tablename where id= '$row[name_id]'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
echo $row ['name'];
```

How to make and how to call the function?

Comment: Before you do anything else, you need to fix the gaping [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) vulnerability in your code.

Comment: If you are making the same query again and again, why not use PDO prepared statement and just execute it whenever you need? that's a better approach.

Comment: @itachi just because it won't help a bit. you can't pass resources between pages

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Yes, it depends on the implementation. but if it is in same page, worth to consider (Specially if all request passes through one file).

Comment: @itachi nope, it is not. You just simple CAN't DO THAT across different requests. And the question is to call this query **"on different pages"**. READ IT FIRST. (not to mention that benefit is hardly measurable)

Comment: @YourCommonSense: interesting point. Let me try creating a super object and calling it from its instance in different pages while all request goes to it. Worth to try atleast ;)

Comment: @itachi it doesn't worth if you know how PHP works. it dies after processing each request, with all it's fancy objects, resources and hookers. You are talking of the front controller which is actually the same PHP script which just using some includes.

Answer (score 0):

sample class stored sample.php

```
class sample
{

    function getName(id)
    {
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM tablename where id='$id'"); 
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
         return $row ['name']; 
    }
}
```

use page include sample.php,then create object,then call getName() function.

```
<?php
 include "db.class.php";
 include "sample.php";
 $ob=new sample();         //create object for smaple class
 $id=12;
 $name=$ob->getName($id);  //call function..
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good idea but first of all you have to create a function to run queries (as you have to run various queries way more often than a particular one)

```
function dbget() {
  /*
  easy to use yet SAFE way of handling mysql queries.

  usage: dbget($mode, $query, $param1, $param2,...);
  $mode - "dimension" of result:
  0 - resource
  1 - scalar
  2 - row
  3 - array of rows

  every variable in the query have to be substituted with a placeholder
  while the avtual variable have to be listed in the function params
  in the same order as placeholders have in the query.

  use %d placeholder for the integer values and %s for anything else
  */
  $args = func_get_args();
  if (count($args) < 2) {
    trigger_error("dbget: too few arguments");
    return false;
  }
  $mode  = array_shift($args);
  $query = array_shift($args);
  $query = str_replace("%s","'%s'",$query); 

  foreach ($args as $key => $val) {
    $args[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
  }

  $query = vsprintf($query, $args);
  if (!$query) return false;

  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    trigger_error("dbget: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
    return false;
  }

  if ($mode === 0) return $res;

  if ($mode === 1) {
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) return $row[0];
    else return NULL;
  }

  $a = array();
  if ($mode === 2) {
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) return $row;
  }
  if ($mode === 3) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) $a[]=$row;
  }
  return $a;
}
```

then you may create this particular function you are asking for

```
function get_name_by_id($id){
    return dbget("SELECT name FROM tablename where id=%d",$id); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably parse the database connection as well

$database_connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

```
function get_row_by_id($id, $database_link){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM tablename where id= '{$id}"); 
    return mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

Usage

```
$row = get_row_by_id(5, $database_connection);
```

[EDIT]
Also it would probably help to wrap the function in a class.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getName($id){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM tablename where id= '$row[name_id]'"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
    return $row ['name']; 
}
```

call the function by

```
$id = 1; //id number
$name = getName($id);
echo $name; //display name
```

Comment: No problem @user1239494. Glad to help, though I don't know who give me me a negative point, HA! hahaha

Comment: It's okay @Deved, the important thing is that I helped you.